# 'TypeError: Categorical.ordered must be the same' when computing dask dataframe after pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, dask

I have a Dask DataFrame with the following structure:

```
Dask DataFrame Structure:
                 A                B                C
npartitions=25                                                    
                 double[pyarrow]  category[known]  category[known]
                             ...              ...              ...
...                          ...              ...              ...
                             ...              ...              ...
                             ...              ...              ...
Dask Name: categorize_block, 13 graph layers
```

B and C are categoricals, and I do pivot_table so I sum A values grouped by C categories as index and B categories as columns:

```py
df.pivot_table(index=C, columns=B, values=A, aggfunc='sum')
```

But after that, when I do `df.compute()` I get *'TypeError: Categorical.ordered must be the same'*

I've been looking for what this error means band I found out it raises in pandas library and not dask. But I have not been able to avoid it.

For now, I am doing `df.compute()` and then, I do `pivot_table()` on the pandas dataframe, so at least it works. But I'm not sure this is the best practice when my dask dataframe has a lot of rows, as the index is a timestamp series for many years, so bringing it all into memory is probably not the best solution.